# Crawl the site and get data from HTML string

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler, goutte

I am using [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) Laravel library in project to get page content and to crawl it.

I can find any element of DOM structure, except in  one of the site i have found the important content placed in `<script>` tag.

The data is placed in javascript variable and i wants to crawl it without heavy string operations. Typical example of such a case

```
$html="var article_content = "Details article string";
var article_twtag = "#Madrid #Barcelona";
var article_twtitle = "Article title"; 
var article_images = new Array (
"http://img.sireasas.com/?i=reuters%2f2017-03-08%2f2017-03-
08t200344z_132005024_mt1aci14762686_rtrmadp_3_soccer-champions-fcb-
  psg_reuters.jpg","",
"0000000000115043","",
"");";
```

Is there any way to crawl the javascript using selector or DOM methods ?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do, was getting the content that existed inside the `script` tag and then extract whatever I wanted through regular expressions.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yoursiteHTML);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('script') as $content) {
    // extract data
}
```

Goutte only receives the HTML response and does not run Javascript code, to get dynamic data, as a browser does.

Comment: I did not test, but I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.your-link-here.com/');

// Find all scripts 
foreach($html->find('script') as $element) 
       echo $element->outertext . '<br>';
```